# I'm using INSERT INTO, but it's returning DATABASE'>

Tags: psql

I'm a novice coder. My website is set up to post blog content directly into our heroku database (long story). I normally insert the blog content in Terminal, accessing the database with `heroku psql`

I use this same format every time to post a blog and it has worked well.

```
INSERT INTO posts (content, title, created_at, updated_at, 
thumbnail_url, summary, author_id) VALUES ('
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

...

```
</html>', 'Title', NOW(), NOW(), '/assets/images/name.jpeg', '“Said” — said no one ever.', 1);
```

Usually it tells me the content has been inserted.

But today it is just ending with this.

`[directoryname]::DATABASE'>`

I don't really even know how to refer to this stuff. I hit Control+C and tried again. Same result.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Nm, in writing this question, I figured out the answer. Somehow a `'` had escaped me in the copy. Not sure how it escaped my command+f. I've noticed sometimes my single quotes `'` aren't actually single quotes. In that they don't come up when I search `'`. I assume they must be some other character. Any idea how to resolve that?